# Updating reports using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, excel, reports

Is there a way to connect an excel table to ArcMap software or a geodatabase so that it updates when data in ArcMap is updated?

Or perhaps there is another software besides excel that could be used to create reports that will update.

Comment: How nice do they have to be? ArcMap does have a so-so reporting function that works with features and nonspatial tables.